# What am I by SC v2

Tags: riddle, word

After the attention of the first riddle, wanted to post a simpler and distracting riddle. Good luck

```
So sharp that I can execute what you want me to. 

Will guide you the way, and when needed I will split your troubles in your head 

So valuable, that you always fight for me 

Standing at the crossroads, waiting for you to find me
```

Hint:

> I am (sometimes) above a wizard's head

hint2:

> I am a single word with multiple meanings

Comment: @AE, this question was protected to prevent "Thanks" answers?

Comment: Don't understand all the negative votes on the question. Anyways, thanks for contrubuting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So sharp that you can execute what I want you to.

> sharpened to a point

Will guide me the way,

> point me in the right direction

and when needed I will split your troubles in your head

> decimal point splits numbers

So valuable, that I always fight for you

> that's the whole point

Standing at the crossroads

> intersection point

waiting for me to find you

> And I finally got to the POINT.

Comment: You beat me to it by a few seconds! :) This is my new guess as well. Though, I'm not sure I understand the part about splitting your troubles.

Comment: Answer is correct but what I thought differently were: pointy weapons are used for excecution, you fight for points like in football, basketball. Great thinking good job :)

Answer (score 3):

Not positive on this one, but I'll take a shot:

> Is it a **compass**?

So sharp that I can execute what you want me to.

> A compass has a sharp end to help you make circles and arcs.

Will guide you the way, and when needed I will split your troubles in your head

> A compass can point you in the right direction; and in "The Golden Compass", a person's soul is split and one part takes the form of an animal.

So valuable, that you always fight for me

> Perhaps another reference to "The Golden Compass"

Standing at the crossroads, waiting for you to find me

> This part is where I become less confident. Any ideas how this fits in?

Comment: It is not mate :)

Comment: @SirSC, would you mind letting us know which part of this is incorrect? I'd love to keep guessing.

Comment: I don't want to spoil guessings that is why I did not make comments, but I can say that your first 2 guesses (only first half of 2nd one) are close to the answer and you can ellaborate on them :) you can find the answer within your own guess

Comment: @SirSC, We get that you don't want to give the puzzle away hint by hint, but nobody wants to come up with possible solutions just to have you say *No*.  Part of the game is you giving a little ground as people get closer (*Warmer, warmer... colder... warmer...*).

Answer (score 2):

> Solution

So sharp that I can execute what you want me to.

> solution is the answer of a question and you execute what solution tells for the problem.

Will guide you the way, and when needed I will split your troubles in your head

> Solution will guide you how you need to execute and it can remove your troubles in your head since you found a solution for a problem.

So valuable, that you always fight for me

> you always fight for a solution for your questions/problems/troubles in your life.

Standing at the crossroads, waiting for you to find me

> There are always solutions to problems and they are waiting at the crossroads for you. You may find it or not...

Comment: Alright, but a solution isn't always necessarily sharp?

Comment: might be best solution/answer (I believe it will still cover solution if it is this)? I am not sure what he meant by "Sharp" there, maybe for "the best solution" of a question/problem to make it a sharp or he thinks something else then solution. Maybe he meant by "sharp" as "desirable" or "clear", and since every solution is "clear" and "desirable" it will cover it. maybe the solution is not "the sharpest" but it is still sharp :) (not every knife is the sharpest but they can still be used to cut something), may @Sir SC answer this?

Comment: answer is not solution. every word has a meaning towards the real "solution" :) including sharp. and each specification that I gave in the riddle "may" be for different meanings for the word

Answer (score 1):

Taking a shot I'm 90% sure about.
The answer is

> The right direction

So sharp that I can execute what you want me to.

> Right direction is aiming towards a specific point/place and hence is sharp, therefore it executes the task of showing the right path, which is what we want.

Will guide you the way, and when needed I will split your troubles in your head

> This is kinda self-explanatory.

So valuable, that you always fight for me

> We always fight to find the right direction in our life

Standing at the crossroads, waiting for you to find me

> Self-explanatory again.

Answer (score 0):

You are

> my mind.

So sharp that I can execute what you want me to:

> A sharp mind can perform many tasks.

Will guide you the way, and when needed I will split your troubles in your head.

> The mind leads the actions, and resolves problems (in your head is literally in your brain).

So valuable, that you always fight for me.

> My mind is my life, my personality.  It defines me, and it is always worth fighting for.

Standing at the crossroads, waiting for you to find me.

> When you have to make a decision (crossroads), you have to stop and think about what you're doing with your mind.

Comment: Nope it is not correct

Comment: @SirSC, Could you qualify in what way this answer does not meet the criteria for the puzzle?

Comment: your answers are too broad. search for specifics of the exact word. giving new hints